# Plink output log coded name?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, putty, plink

First of all, sorry if the question doesn't make sense, I'm not the best at English. My question is, I'm trying to save Plink session into a log, that part is now done:

```
Plink.exe -v -pw [PW] -batch -m C:\BATS\comandosx3.txt root@[IP] > C:\BATS\Logs\outputdegradado.log 2>&1
```

Now my question is, can I code the output.log name to be stored with date and time so everytime the program starts doesn't write over the last session? for example output2009.log

Comment: I assume you mean `plink root@IP somecommand > c:\BATS\Logs\output.log 2>&1`, right?

Comment: yes, the full code is: Plink.exe -pw [PW] -batch -m C:\BATS\program.txt root@[IP[ > c:\BATS\Logs\output.log 2>&1

Answer (score 0):

I didnt know it was related to the batch file, i thought it was plink specific code. Watching for batch specific code, i end up with a single file that registry the date and time at the start of the program.

```
@echo off
set logfile=C:\BATS\Degradado\Logs\Seguimiento.log
echo starting Plink.exe at %date% %time% >> %logfile%
Plink.exe -v -pw [PW] -batch -m C:\BATS\Degradado\comandosx3.txt root@[IP] oas >> %logfile% 2>&1
```

Thanks @martin-prikryl for the suggestion